# Deleting all tuples except ones with the smallest gap between integers, in the list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to delete all tuples from the list of tuples except those pairs of integers, which are closest to each other.

For example, I have a list:

`[(7, 36), (8, 36), (9, 36), (12, 36), (13, 37), (15, 37), (23, 37), (65, 78)]`

And I want it to look like this:

`[(12, 36), (23, 37), (65, 78)]`

So that the first value must be the biggest or *the gap between two digits in tuple must be the smallest*, in another words. The thing is, I don't know in advance neither the fist number, nor the second. I also don't know how many tuples are appended.

***python3.5 is used***

*UPD: Thanks a lot for your answers! All of them work nice after your edits.*

Comment: so do I get it right, that for every occuring second value you want to find the biggest first value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd tackle this with an `OrdereDict`:

In Python 2, I'd write it like this:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> l = [(7, 36), (8, 36), (9, 36), (12, 36), (13, 37), (15, 37), (23, 37), (65, 78)]
>>> 
>>> seen = OrderedDict()
>>> for first, second in l:
...     if first > seen.get(second, None):
...         seen[second] = first
... 
>>> [(x, y) for y, x in seen.items()]
[(12, 36), (23, 37), (65, 78)]
```

Note that everything will be greater than the fallback value `None` for `seen.get`.

Python 3+ solution, where you can't compare an integer to `None`:

```
>>> seen = OrderedDict()
>>> for first, second in l:
...     if second not in seen or first > seen[second]:
...         seen[second] = first
... 
>>> [(x, y) for y, x in seen.items()]
[(12, 36), (23, 37), (65, 78)]
```

Both solutions are not limited to tuples of positive integers.
Runtime for this is in O(n) because there's no O(n log(n)) sorting involved.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > NoneType()` while executing the loop

Comment: @AlexeyVilchansky oh wow, this seems to be because you are using py3. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a dict of maximum first elements for each distinct second element:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [(7, 36), (8, 36), (9, 36), (12, 36), (13, 37), (15, 37), (23, 37), (65, 78)]

d = defaultdict(lambda: -sys.maxsize)  # assume very small default
for pair in l:
    d[pair[1]] = max(d[pair[1]], pair[0])
result = sorted([(v, k) for k, v in d.iteritems()],  key=lambda x: x[1])  # sort by second elements

print(result)
```

Comment: When I try to execute `d[pair[1]] = max(d[pair[1]], pair[0])` I get `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'maxint'`

Comment: Code works fine here (Python 2.7.10, Ubuntu 15.10). Which Python version are you using? Instead of `-sys.maxint - 1` (smallest possible integer), you can also really just pick any number that is smaller than the values you expect to encounter.

Comment: I've specified in question, that I use python3.5

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a dictionary that keeps track of the highest value.  Then, create a sorted list from it:

```
highest = {}
for value, key in tuples:
    highest[key] = max(highest.get(key, 0), value)

sorted_list = sorted((x[::-1] for x in highest.items()), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I split your list according to the second item and retrieve the tuple with maximal first item:

```
mylist = [(7, 36), (8, 36), (9, 36), (12, 36), (13, 37), (15, 37), (23, 37), (65, 78)]
get2item = lambda x: x[1]
mylist.sort(key = get2item)
newlist = []
while mylist:
    enditem = get2item(mylist[-1])
    endlist = filter(lambda x: get2item(x)==enditem, mylist)
    mylist[-len(endlist):] = []
    endlist.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
    newlist.append(endlist[-1])

print newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list=[(7, 36), (8, 36), (9, 36), (12, 36), (13, 37), (15, 37), (23, 37), (65, 78),(1, 36)]
adict={}
for v,k in your_list:
    if not adict.get(k):
        adict[k]=[v]
    else:
        adict[k].append(v)

#print(adict)
result=[(max(v),k) for k,v in adict.items()]
print(sorted(result))
```